# Java / HashMap / Performance

Tags: java, performance, hashmap

Here's the `put()` method of my HashMap implementation. It runs about 1500 ms for 100 000 element, while `Collections`'s HashMap runs in 8 ms.

**What makes so huge difference in performance?**

( My hash function is simply based on hashCode(), the load factor is around 0,6 so it should perform well)

```
public boolean put(K key, V value)
{
    if (size > cap*LOAD_FACTOR) expand();

    int i;  
    for(i=hash(key);container[i] != null;i=(i+1) % cap)
    {
        if(container[i].key.equals(key))
        {
            container[i] = new Entry<K,V>(key,value);
            return true;
        }               
    }

    container[i] = new Entry<K,V>(key,value);
    size++;

    return true;
```

Comment: How did you measure those numbers? If you didn't use a proper benchmark tool, you can throw them off the balcony.

Comment: Console and `System.nanotime()` with warm-up phase  :)

Comment: you usually cannot compete with the JVM implementations. they are highly optimized for different types, memory allocations and such. some containers work directly with the underlying native code which you cannot achieve with pure Java implementation

Comment: Tunaki is right, a limited number of unreliable tests doesn't mean anything

Comment: If your test is correct (see comments why it may not), you need to know where you spend your time. expand() is a likely candidate. How many times do you call expand()?

Comment: @GerdCastan expand() doubles capacity, if it triples it the algorithm is much slower, i tried it with x2.5, that reduced time to 1100 ms.

Comment: If you know the number of entries in advance, you could set the initial capacity. Does not fix the root cause but might be good enough since you never expand()

Comment: Why do you have `new Entry(...)` two times? Shouldn't the first one just set a field variable? Also, you should probably use the hash values to check for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `%` is a very expensive operation, and in fact HashMap doesn't use it all, i.e. its size is always a power of two to allow a mask to do the job.  In your case a single operation could call `%` many times especially if your load factor is not high enough.
Try removing `%`.

Note: if you use open addressing like you have, you need to make the load factor lower e.g. less than 0.5. HashMap has a higher load factor as it handles collisions a different way.

Also note that;

- creating a new medium lived object is very expensive, I would avoid that when updating the value.
- you can cache the hashCode to speed up the expand(), meaning you can compare the hashCode before performing equals()

Comment: You were completely right about % operator. I replaced it with `i = (i < (cap-1)) ? i+1 : 0` and the performance improved to 250 ms. Then i reduced loadfactor slightly, and now it runs 35 :) Thanks!